# DL-Query for range value does not result as expected

Tags: owl, protege, dlquery

I'm new in Protege (Protege 5.2.0). I put some data properties to a class as in the picture below:
[image: let's focus on the last line]
Let's focus on the last line.

Then, I used DL-Query like this

```
OilPalm that hasGrowthRate some xsd:float[>=50.0]
```

I expected that the class will be returned, but it does not. I'm stuck in this problem.

Any help, please?

Comment: But your query doesn't match the class, why do you think so? `>=40.0` is **not** `>=50.0`

Comment: I mean that >=50.0 will also return classes which have value more than 50.0, and I think that 55.0 will be also included.

Comment: I guess you're wrong here. You class defines *"oil palms that have a growth rate bigger than 50"*. And the other class defines *"something that has some groth rate between 40 and 55"*. I don't see any relationship between both here, neither as subclass nor as superclass. You can simply look at both ranges `[50, ∞)` and `[40, 55]`, there is no containment just an overlap, right?

Comment: Your query and the class expression you're interested in have a common subclass (things with growth rate between 50 and 55), but that does not imply one is subclass of the other. Also, the class expression you refer is anonymous - so, whether it is found in a search depends on other factors. A reasoner will not return it explicitly.

Comment: The class which has `hasGrowthRate` is a subclass of `OilPalm`. I'm sorry for not specified this in the question. I have tried for non range data and it doesn't have problem (for bigger than query). Is this situation make the problem clear?

Comment: There is no "problem". Your assumption is wrong, that's all. Please read my explanation and understand that there is no subsumption relationship

Comment: BTW, if your query was `hasGrowthRate some xsd:float[>= 50.0f , <= 51.0f]`, `OilPalm` shouldn't be returned neither as a subclass, nor as a superclass.

Comment: I do not understand DL-Query completely yet. But if DL-Query only resulting the classes with all possibilities covered in the query (not just overlap) then my assumption is wrong as mentioned by @AKSW. If this is true, then my question has meet the answer.